# Color blindness in the Workplace

Tags: interviewing, software-industry, disability

I am a software developer and I am colorblind. This is a mild disability, but it's still quite inconvenient when I use some parts of a software (IDEs for example).

I understand this can be quite good for the company's image ("we have 6 % of disabled employees, we are open-minded" and such), but it's still quite problematic for me, as I will have to spend a few hours or days configuring my computer tools, and I still won't be able to perform some simple task, thus will have to ask for someone's help. This will at most take 20 minutes per week, but I'm still uncomfortable disturbing a colleague who is working/busy.

So here is my question: should I or not talk about it during interviews?

Comment: Related [question about CVs and resumes](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/12336/should-a-disability-be-included-on-the-resume-or-cover-letter) and [very very similar question about disabilities in interviews](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/9921/how-do-i-mention-i-have-carpal-tunnel-syndrome-on-an-interview).

Comment: @enderland thanks I only looked up color blind problem and I didn't find those questions.

Comment: "*... as I will have to spend a few hours or days configuring my computer tools...*" You mean *every day for as long as you work there?* Or just for the first few weeks? What kind of tools need to be constantly configured and adjusted, in perpetuity? I admit I like heavily customized configurations of Eclipse installations, and yes, it took a few hours at first to get it all "just right", but now I can export configurations and load them to new workspaces or installations. I think *most* people customize their tools, I don't think that should be a problem, even if you spend a few more hours.

Comment: No. a) it can be compensated by adjusting the colour scheme of your computer. b) for the big IDEs there typically are ways to increase the contrast - i estimate that you may spend one time a few hours, and after that it will be fine